# How to display Javascript Variable value to HTML href tag

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting

i am rewriting my url and category name passing in to url. Now i am creating  Url Friendly String using JS  function is:

```
function getUrlFriendlyString(str)
{
   // convert spaces to '-'
   //alert(str);
   str = str.replace(/ /g, "-");
   // Make lowercase
   str = str.toLowerCase();
   // Remove characters that are not alphanumeric or a '-'
   str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, "");
   // Combine multiple dashes (i.e., '---') into one dash '-'.
   str = str.replace(/[-]+/g, "-");
   return str;
}
```

now on HTML page this JS function is giving a string value in JS like

```
<? $cat_name= 'Personalized Chocolates / Gift'; ?>
<script>var url=getUrlFriendlyString("<?=$cat_name;?>");</script>
```

i want to pass **var url** value in html tag href like that

```
<a  href="<?PHP echo SITE_URL;?>/category/<script>document.write(url);</script>/<?=$data_2['cat_id'];?>"
```

but

```
<script>document.write(url);</script>
```

not giving their value and coming url is like that

```
http://localhost/ecom/category/<script>document.writeln(url);</script>/105
```

required url is

```
http://localhost/ecom/category/personalized-chocolates-gift/105
```

any idea how i can show proper url using js string?

i can save **var url** value in PHP variable

Comment: element.href = yourVariable;

Comment: I can do this in php and i m also doing but i want that on client side to use less server resource. we are shifting lot of possible functionality on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me

you can take **var url** value in php variable and use in your href tag

```
<? $cat_name= 'Personalized Chocolates / Gift'; ?>
<script>var url=getUrlFriendlyString("<?=$cat_name;?>");</script>
```

and

```
<?php
        $m="<script>document.write(url);</script>";
        echo $m; // output is : personalized-chocolates-gift
   ?>
```

this will not give you same o/p inside href, will give you o/p your js code because inside $m js code is saved and href not converting js into string o/p

i hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't include an element (such as `<script>...</script>`) in the middle of an attribute value.

If you are going to take this approach, then you need to write out the entire anchor element using JavaScript.

An alternative approach would be to set a default value in the HTML, then access the element with DOM in a script that appears after the element is complete.

A better approach would be to rewrite the `getUrlFriendlyString` function in PHP and run it on your server.

Comment: Dear thanks for answer. 
I can do this in php and i m also doing but i want that on client side to use less server resource. we are shifting lot of possible functionality on client side

Comment: That's a false economy. That sort of operation is cheap (in relative terms) to begin with. Server resources are also cheap these days. Moving it to client will add the complexity of multiple target environments for the code to run under (which increases development and testing costs), and increase the likelihood of failure (since JS might not run due to network glitches / bad spam filtering / loss of mobile connections / users disabling JS / etc).

Answer (score 0):

this may help you JS in HTML Code `redirectTo()` is JS Function

```
<a onclick="redirectTo();">click here</a>
```